# React and getClientBoundingRect

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a piece of React html like to this:

```
<div id="grandparent">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
 Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas 
 congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur 
 <span class='container' style='position:relative'>
   <span class='hilited'>ante hendrerit. </span>
   <div id='grandchild' style='position:absolute; top:...'>
     Stuff...
   </div>
 </span> 
 Donec et mollis dolor....
</div>
```

I want the 'grandchild' div to appear just below the 'hilited' span and just inside the left edge of the 'grandparent' div, so I plan to calculate grandchild's left position by taking the difference of getClientBoundingRect().left from the grandparent and container elements.

Since this is all generated by React, I don't have the elements at creation time. I'm guessing that I need to collect refs to 'grandparent' and 'container', pass them down to 'grandchild' with state/props and calculate things there. Initial attempts have failed.

What's the best way to take this on?

Edit:

[image: Diagram of desired layout]

Note: The whole thing needs to nest. Sometimes 'grandchild' will contain text of its own which will have a highlighted section with its own grandchild nested below.

Comment: Firstly, have you tried a pure css approach? Next, you can do this via putting one ref each on both hilited and grandchild, then using them to position the div within componentDidMount method in grandparent component.

Comment: Also, refs shouldn't be passed down the hierarchy, it creates a possibility of mem leaks.

Comment: Pure css would be great. Is there a way?

Comment: Put up a screenshot of how the element should look. We can then discuss possible css solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a refs solution.

Add this function as ref on grandchild:

```
function(el) {
  if (el) {
    var gpar = el.parentElement.parentElement;
    var par = el.parentElement;
    var offset = gpar.getClientBoundingRect().left - 
                 par.getClientBoundingRect().left;
    el.style.left = (offset + 15).toString().concat('px');
  }
}
```

I still wouldn't mind seeing a pure css solution.